# Encoding issue when sending HTML via PHP cURL post

Tags: php, html, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to send a very simple HTML structure over a post done via PHP cURl.

`<html><body><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>`

The post request is a json encoded array that is like this :

> json_encode(array('pageId'=>'2'),'html'=>'<p>Hello World!</p>');

`%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3E%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E`

PHP file is saved as UTF-8 .. What else can I do?

Comment: I'm sorry, what? Please post all the relevant code as well as what error have you come across. By `the request is a json` you mean the request content right? And I don't think that second parameter on `json_encode` belongs there.

Comment: What is your idea ? to post json via curl to where ?

Comment: @Svetlio , I'm editing a page HTML via a web service

Comment: @Naughty.Coder with Javascript ?

Comment: Naughty.Coder where are you trying to post this to? Are you sure the requested application knows how to handle json as the content or is it just a regular php page and you want to get that piece of html through ´$_POST´?

Comment: Please put ALL code that could be relevant here and describe exactly what you would like to happen.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably outputting an html error page because your close parens is in the wrong place.

```
json_encode(array('pageId'=>'2'),'html'=>'<p>Hello World!</p>');
```

Should be

```
json_encode(array('pageId'=>'2','html'=>'<p>Hello World!</p>'));
```